# Issue in creating json with bash for kafka topics

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a json of the Kafka topics through bash script which may be used for the reassignment of the partitions later on.

I was successfully able to get the JSON when I was creating the topics array which is coming from a file using the new line as the IFS. But when I am trying to create an array from the output of the command it is giving different JSON.

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
topics=( $(docker run -it confluentinc/cp-kafka bash -c "kafka-topics --zookeeper kafka-0:2181 --list") )
printf "%s\n" "${topics[@]}"
echo -e "{\"topics\":["
printf '{"topic": "%s"},\n' "${topics[@]}" | sed '$s/,$//'
echo -e "],"
echo -e  "\"version\":1"
echo -e "}"
```

Output:

```
__confluent.support.metrics
__consumer_offsets
example1
example2
example3
example4
example5
{"topics":[
"},opic": "__confluent.support.metrics
"},opic": "__consumer_offsets
"},opic": "example1
"},opic": "example2
"},opic": "example3
"},opic": "example4
"}topic": "example5
],
"version":1
}
```

Comment: Strange, [can't replicate](http://tpcg.io/EoGaW3). Do you have `\r` characters in your file? Do you have `\r` characters in "${topics[@]}"? Try dos2unix or similar. Can you post the output of `echo "${topics[@]}" | hexdump -C` or maybe better `for  i in "${topics[@]}"; do echo "$i" | hexdump -C; done` to check what characters are there. If `topics[1]='example1'$'\r'` then you just observe that the cursor comes back after the string, which would explain it.

Comment: Yes, I am not getting this error on any other Linux system but ```Container Linux by CoreOS stable (1911.5.0)```

Comment: Also, check IFS, Set  your IFS to reasonable value, to default IFS=$' \r\n' or maybe just `$'\r'`.

Comment: Just a note but this can be done more concisely with a call to jq, if that is an option to install for you.

Comment: Yes, I can use jq. Do you have the syntax? I am not very much pro in using jq.